# How to launch a script using an alert in gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to generate an alert in Monitoring and Login and I want that when that alert is triggered, my script is executed (which I already have generated in my cloud repository), how could I do it?

Comment: A possible workflow could be after alert is generated, you will need pubsub to ingest that message, which in turn will trigger cloud function which is a product that just runs your code.

Comment: Create you alert and choose PubSub as notification channel. Then follow the Nadia answer to plug your PubSub to a Cloud Functions, Cloud Run or whatever you want that can process your event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be possible with [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) this could [trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling) a declaration of what occurrence should cause your function to execute.

You can use [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub), so when an event is presenting on the system a message is published to a Pub/Sub topic that is specified when a function is deployed. Every message published to this topic will trigger function execution with message contents passed as input data.

In the next guide “[Alert-based event](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-pubsub-drainer)” you can find the steps to implement this solution.